# How to get data from firebase by using uid

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app I want the user name to be displayed after user logins for that i have used the Uid but I am not recieving data from `firebase`

Using RN>57.8

this is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){

firebase.database()
   .ref('users/'+this.state.uid)
    .on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    const name1 = snapshot.val().name;
    alert(name1)
})
}
```

and

```
componentDidMount(){

firebase.database()
   .ref(`users/${this.state.uid}`)
    .on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    const name1 = snapshot.val().name;
    alert(name1)
})
}
```

I want to show alert message with the name of the user but it is not working whereas if i write the path directly as shown below i am able to get the alert

Example:

```
.ref('users/ALM5456N3NNN35HFR56L')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this to get the name

```
firebase.database()
   .ref(`users/${this.state.uid}`).on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    console.log(snapshot.val());

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your time i tried this just now i got  alert  null

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13YiCGfsLak_mS5waF-3pIVoX7HBuPhzm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have modified the answer try doing it like this.

Comment: i tried no alert showing and getting warning  possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0):typeError:null is not an object (evaluating 'userData.name')

Comment: I have modified my answer. Console like this and check what are you getting in this.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using uid for reference in your database?

Comment: thank you so much this worked for me but i am getting all users data not only who sign in

Comment: Give the proper reference, then you will be able to get the data for that.